# Update built-in vim on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim

I know this might be more appropriate at Ask Different, but as I tried adding tags there, there was no `vim` tag, only `macvim`. So I figured I might get a better audience here.

In the Terminal, I do the following

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jan 31 2010 13:33:49)
```

When I browse to http://www.vim.org, I see a news item

> Vim 7.3 released!

How do I update my built-in vim? I would very much like to do it cleanly (i.e. no duplicate installations, or any additional downloads, no macports, etc.)

I considered using Mercurial (as I already use it for other things), as per the instructions [here](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

```
$ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com.hg/ vim
$ cd vim/src
$ make
```

But I think that would make a duplicate installation. Despite my "clean" requirement as mentioned above, "unclean" solutions are also welcome, since maybe there really is no other way.

Comment: In general I think it's best to not muck with the Apple installed bits and use macports/homebrew/etc. or build it yourself and install it in `/usr/local/`. Not like it's gonna take up a lot of space.

Comment: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases <- you can download the lastest macvim snapshots here

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, you want to install over your existing Vim, for better or worse :-) This is a **bad idea** and it is **not the "clean" way to do it.** Why? Well, OS X expects that nothing will ever change in /usr/bin unbeknownst to it, so any time you overwrite stuff in there you risk breaking some intricate interdependency. And, Let's say you do break something -- there's no way to "undo" that damage. You will be sad and alone. You may have to reinstall OS X.

### Part 1: A better idea

The "clean" way is to install in a separate place, and make the new binary higher priority in the $PATH. Here is how I recommend doing that:

```
$ # Create the directories you need
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/bin
$ # Download, compile, and install the latest Vim
$ cd ~
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/vim-mirror/vim or git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
$ 
$ cd vim
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ # Add the binary to your path, ahead of /usr/bin
$ echo 'PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ # Reload bash_profile so the changes take effect in this window
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Voila! Now when we use vim we will be using the new one. But, to get back to our old configuration in the event of huge f*ckups, we can just delete the /opt directory.

```
$ which vim
/opt/local/bin/vim
$ vim --version | head -n 2
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 27 2011 20:55:46)
MacOS X (unix) version
```

See how clean this is.

I recommend not to install in /usr/local/bin when you want to override binaries in /usr/bin, because by default OS X puts /usr/bin higher priority in $PATH than /usr/local/bin, and screwing with that opens its own can of worms.... So, that's what you **SHOULD** do.

### Part 2: The "correct" answer (but a bad idea)

Assuming you're set on doing that, you are definitely on track. To install on top of your current installation, you need to set the "prefix" directory. That's done like this:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/vim-mirror/vim or git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

You can pass "configure" a few other options too, if you want. Do "./configure --help" to see them. I hope you've got a backup before you do it, though, in case something goes wrong....

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if I should upvote this... It answers the question...  But it's a bad idea and doesn't explain why... So perhaps I should downvote it?

Comment: Great answer, but as a *nix beginner I am curious as to why you chose went to ~ to install vim.  Also, what does that ./configure... line do?  Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexMA Putting the source in `~`, i.e. your home directory, is completely arbitrary. Feel free to download it to wherever you want. Once you've installed it, you can delete the directory, too (the source is no longer necessary at that point).

Comment: Thanks a lot for a tip! I did adjust your configure for Python, PERL and Ruby support to `./configure --prefix /opt/local --enable-perlinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-rubyinterp=yes --with-features=huge --with-python-config-dir=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`

Comment: "Voila! Now when we use vim we will be using the old one. "

I think this is a typo and you meant to say "we will be using the *new* one"

Comment: Hey one question, haven't you had E254 errors after this installation? This is an error related with allocation of colors, and it is displayed every time you open vim from the console

Comment: After install according your suggestion, now I want to uninstall it. How shoud I do to uninstall vim if /opt/local has other app data? @RobertMartin

Comment: It's an awesome idea, but, I got an error while running make for OSX 10.9, error: os_macosx.m: Objective-C compiler not installed on this system
make[1]: *** [objects/os_macosx.o] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

Comment: I used: `./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/opt/local
` to avoid python incompatibility error

Answer (score 122):

Don't overwrite the built-in Vim.

Instead, install it from source in a different location or via Homebrew or MacPorts in their default location then add this line to your .bashrc or .profile:

```
alias vim='/path/to/your/own/vim'
```

and/or change your `$PATH` so that it looks into its location before the default location.

The best thing to do, in my opinion, is to simply download the latest MacVim which comes with a very complete vim executable and use it in Terminal.app like so.

```
alias vim='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim' # or something like that, YMMV
```

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.8.2, the path is slightly different: `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`

Comment: No, it's the same on every Mac OS X version. I just made a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @fabian789: First because it's useless, two because soft is better than hard, three because default Vim works and if something goes wrong you may very well not have a working Vim anymore, four a system upgrade may overwrite your Vim and the list could probably go on and on…

Comment: ...or `alias vim='mvim -v'`. But both of these fail with `sudo vim` using the old version. I would suggest using @RobertMartin's answer or a package manager. There's also one other option: [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/178956) by [Slizzered](http://serverfault.com/users/53621/slizzered) on serverfault.com, which allows you to pass aliases to `sudo`.

Comment: "Aliases are shortcuts for an interactive shell; they are not used by other processes," says this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466767/gitconfig-not-following-bash-alias-for-default-editor-command 

Therefore, this doesn't work for, say `git difftool` or `git commit`.

Comment: @jasonszhao, indeed, better to configure Git directly with the desired command.

Answer (score 58):

Like Eric, I used homebrew, but I used the default recipe. So:

```
brew install mercurial
brew install vim
```

And after restarting the terminal homebrew's vim should be the default. If not, you should update your `$PATH` so that `/opt/homebrew/bin` is before `/usr/bin`. E.g. add the following to your `.profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

*Note: Previous versions of Homebrew did install to `/usr/local`, so in that case you have to use `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/opt/homebrew/bin`.*

Comment: @Beau This is not correct, homebrew does have a formula for vim: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb

Comment: Sorry, my fault! A `brew update` did indeed give me back a formula for vim.

Comment: Fix `vi` symlinks: `[sudo] ln -sf /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/bin/vi`

Comment: I added my `vi` symlink to `/usr/local/bin`: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/local/bin/vi`

Comment: "And after restarting the terminal homebrew's vim" that's when it suddenly struck me - i need to turn it off and on again for the new vim to work. Thanks man

Comment: I was missing to restart the iTerm2 to make homebrew's vim the default. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

A note to romainl's answer: aliases don't work together with sudo because only the first word is checked on aliases. To change this add another alias to your .profile / .bashrc:

`alias sudo='sudo '`

With this change `sudo vim` will behave as expected!

Answer (score 6):

On Yosemite, install vim using `brew` and the `override-system-vi` option. This will automatically install vim with the features of the ['huge' vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#H) install.

```
brew install vim --with-override-system-vi
```

The output of this command will show you where brew installed vim. In that folder, go down into `/bin/vim` to actually run vim. This is your command to run vim from any folder:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.873/bin/vim
```

Then alias this command by adding the following line in your .bashrc:

```
alias vim="/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.873/bin/vim"
```

EDIT: Brew flag `--override-system-vi` has been deprecated. Changed for `--with-override-system-vi`. Source: https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/401

Comment: like this you have to update the alias at every time you update vim. Also, it is not necessary to add the exact location as an alias since vim automatically adds the binary to /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Brew flag `--override-system-vi` is now deprecated. Use `--with-override-system-vi` insted.

Comment: @ahuelamo Do you have a source? If so, feel free to edit and source. Thanks

Comment: @Private Well, that was suggested by brew itself. You can find it here as well https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/401

Comment: Adding the alias is redundant when using the override flag.

Comment: DId you test that?

Answer (score 1):

`brew install vim --override-system-vi`

Comment: Gives no description or reference as to why this command should be run.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://www.prioritized.net/blog/upgrading-vim-on-os-x) was helpful for me. I used the "Homebrew built Vim" solution, which in my case saved the new version in /usr/local/bin. At this point, the post suggested hiding the system vim, which didn't work for me, so I used an alias instead.

```
$ brew install vim
$ alias vim='/path/to/new/vim
$ which vim
vim: aliased to /path/to/new/vim
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried this but brew must have replaced the path automatically. Calling `vim` seemed to open the new vim (after opening a new Terminal)

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy agreed, no need to create an alias here if using homebrew.  Both starting a new shell and re-sourcing my bashrc in the existing terminal both worked to update the vim command to the new homebrew version.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed vim by:

```
brew install vim
```

now the new vim is accessed by `vim` and the old vim (built-in vim) by `vi`

Comment: Worked for me after opening a new terminal.