# Compiling Vim on OS X 10.10.3 does not work

Tags: macos, gcc, vim

[I am not sure whether this fits here or should be moved to apple.SE]

Today I got the idea to recompile my vim in order to get the latest updates. I have once or twice before followed the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7211910/2397253) so I did it again. I cloned the repo and ran

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local/ --with-features=huge
```

(I tried with no options, problem persists)
Invariably, compilation aborts when the compiler attempts to parse ObjC-Files (for whatever reason it has to)

```
/usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:22:4: error: unknown type name 'instancetype'
 - (instancetype)self;
```

It seems the compiler does not know the current Objective-C standard.
There seems to be a problem with `gcc` because I found [this bug ticket](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63651). However, the most recent update on this is from last year.

Can someone suggest a way to make this work?

*EDIT*: I know I could install it via homebrew or macports; yet I am still very curious how to fix this particular problem.

Also I tried manually changing the compiler to `clang` like so

```
CC=clang ./configure --prefix=/opt/local/ --with-features=huge
```

After simply setting `CC=clang` before running (which is what the configure help seems to advertise) and seeing it did nothing. However when specifying a compiler this way (I tried the same with `gcc` as well), many `configure` checks turn out `no` and it eventually aborts.

Comment: Yeah install [Macports](http://macports.org) and type `sudo port install vim` (you should install the Xcode 6.3 command line utilities first).

Comment: @trojanfoe Well yes, I use macports and could use it to install vim, but I'd still like to know why manual compilation seemingly does not currently work.

Comment: I guess it's because you don't have an official Objective-C SDK with `gcc` or `clang`, only with Xcode.

Comment: I have the latest XCode and all the stuff it comes with installed.

Comment: And `gcc` is configured with Objective-C support?

Comment: I had assumed so, but how do I find out? I suppose XCode uses `clang` for iOS compilation so I never tested `gcc`.

Comment: I don't remember the command line options, but that would be my assumption.  Using `clang` from Xcode is the only compiler I would consider using.

Comment: I updated the question. I seem to miss something in trying to manually set the complier, any ideas?

Comment: If you have a (custom) version of `clang` installed as well as Xcode, then you don't know which `clang` is being used.  I would use `CC="xcrun clang" ./configure...`. Or `/usr/bin/clang` perhaps.

Comment: Interesting. Although `which clang` returns `/usr/bin/clang`, manually specifying the path like you suggested appears to do the trick. It now successfully compiles. If you care to make an answer out of this, I will accept it, although an explanation for why gcc can't do it anymore would also be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that `gcc` has not been configured with Objective-C support (it supports at least C, C++ and Objective-C and the installer can opt for whatever support they want).

It's possible that the 3rd-party `clang` is in the same boat.  However I know that the Xcode version supports all 3 languages and will pick-up the correct OSX Cocoa runtime libraries, so using that appears to have solved the issue:

```
$ CC="xcrun clang" ./configure --prefix=/opt/local/ --with-features=huge
```

However just using `clang` should have worked as well, if `which clang` returns `/usr/bin/clang` as you say it does, so I'm at a loss to explain exactly why that didn't work.