# vim OSX deadly signal ABRT on vsplit

Tags: macos, vim

There seems to be a major problem with a fairly basic use case of `vim` installed on OSX 10.10.5 via homebrew. Try the following with any `file1` and `file2`:

```
$ vim file1
:vsplit or :split file2
Ctrl-W arrow back to file1
make any kind of edit to file1 and then :wq
```

The editor then segfaults and backs out to terminal with the following message:

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is my output of `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul  9 2015 23:58:42)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
<bunch of default runtime options>
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

Anyone else encounter this? Should I downgrade or patch my version of vim?

Comment: You should upgrade. Since your version is 5 years old now. (Not the 7.3 in the version output). Since you said you installed it with homebrew you might need to pass `--override-system-vim` when installing it

Comment: Yes, you are using the default Vim instead of the upgraded one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is the same issue that was discussed on [YCM issue 1351](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1351).

In a nutshell, the problem of Vim build on MacOS is it messed up the Python directories when there are multiple Python installations. To verify this on your Mac, just type the following commend:

```sh
otool -L `which vim` | grep Python
```

If the output result contains more than **1 line**, your Vim build is probably messed up.

To fix this problem, the YCM issue suggests you can remove `--with-python-config-dir` from `configure` file of Vim. Or you can specify the correct Python directory to that parameter.

I also found a [Homebrew trick](https://blog.sharpbai.com/2015/04/%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3mac%E4%B8%8Bvim-caught-deadly-signal-abrt%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98/) which can fix this problem without pain. Here it is:

```sh
brew reinstall python --framework
brew reinstall vim
```

I tested the Homebrew trick and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to vim 7.4 solved this, but OSX did not make it convenient to upgrade. Unfortunately your own solution to this will be strongly coupled to your specific environment, but this thread is a good place to start:

[Update built-in vim on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211820/update-built-in-vim-on-mac-os-x)