# VIMRUNTIME and a new vim folder

Tags: macos, vim

I just compiled a new vim version with certain features that wasn't previously available on the typical mac os x homebrew vim version. I placed this vim version in the folder '/opt/local' (as in the second response to this question: [Update built-in vim on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211820/update-built-in-vim-on-mac-os-x)) in order to avoid messing with the previous vim install.

However, now I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/Profile/.vimrc:
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
line   22:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
line   25:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
```

First, I tried updating the `runtimepath` in my `.vimrc` with: 
`let &runtimepath.=','.string('/opt/local/share/vim/vim74')`, and now `:set runtimepath?` shows:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim,~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after,'/opt/local/share/vim/vim74'
```

which to me seemed like it might be on the right track. Unfortunately, the errors from above still showed up. Typing in `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` gives me `/usr/share/vim/vim74`, which is the location of my old vim version.

Do I need to update my `$VIMRUNTIME` in `~/.zshrc`?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your path seems to be set properly. (In my case, it was blocked by system default). So, if you change hour runtime variable, it should work fine.

Comment: Could you show us the actual commands you used for building Vim?