# .gitconfig not following bash alias for default editor command?

Tags: git, bash, config, alias

In my `.bash_profile`, I have the `vim` command aliased to `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`.

For the following line in my `.gitconfig` file,

```
 [core]
        editor = vim
```

git runs system vim rather than following the alias specified above. If I manually change it to match the complete path of MacVim's `Vim` command above, it works fine.

Is there any way to make `.gitconfig` follow the bash alias, rather than having to set the complete MacVim path? (I have all my user config files synchronized across multiple machines, some of which don't run MacVim.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases are shortcuts for an interactive shell; they are not used by other processes. Just specify the exact path you want in `.gitconfig`; you only have to type it once.

Comment: Alternatively, create a symlink to the vim you want to run in some folder within the PATH.